# how SVM classifier works in hand written character recognition?

Tags: matlab

I am working on hand written Hindi numerals recognition I want to apply SVM classifier. But I do not how SVM classifier works please any one explain how SVM classifier works in character recognition... Thanks in advance..

Comment: This is an extremely broad machine learning question, and thus is more of a math question, not a coding question... Googling it will probably be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any classifier works by being fed with numerical features together with a class index. This is the training phase.

During the recongition phase, the classifier somehow "interpolates" between the training samples and guesses the probable class.

What really matters is to feed with sufficiently many features that are discriminant, i.e. that significantly differ from one character to the next.

You can check the discriminative power of a feature as follows:

- train with the half of you training set;
- classify the remaining half with the classifier and count the errors;
- compare the errors achieved with and without using this feature.

If the difference is small, this feature might be of no use.

If the error rate remains too large, add more (discriminant) features.